# Jupyter (Python): Display .tex tables from .txt files

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a text file that contains a Latex table similar to this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
\toprule
{} &    2011 &    2012 &    2013 &    2014 \\
\midrule
Number of Firms           &    1500 &    1500 &    1500 &    1500 \\
...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Is it possible to call this `.txt` file to be displayed in a Jupyter notebook with the correct latex format? By format, I mean to view the actual table and not the `.tex` code. 
Is there a Python package that can convert the latex table in the `.txt` file into HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the problem completely but if it is rendering latex you have magic provided for that:

%%latex

after which you can put your [latex](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) and it will render it when the cell is executed. 
Also another option is to load Latex:

```
from IPython.display import Latex
Latex(r"""\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0 
\end{eqnarray}""")
```

Comment: I see. But what if I load my latex table in a string like this: `s = open('
         'Description_Statistics.txt').read()` and s contains the latex code but in a string. is there a way to display this datable. I tried the `Latex` and `display` function but no luck. thanks

Comment: I tried to run the above latex example from a txt file and it worked. If you have used some personal add on, defined styles etc, in latex that might cause it not to work.
This worked
z = open('testing_latex.txt','r').read()
from IPython.display import Latex
Latex(z)